# Why are some guidewire's tips bend for endovascular interventions?

Tags: cardiology, cardiovascular-disease, coronary-bypass

I am working in a medical-physics field and want to summarize some information about guidewires. I have read, that guidewires can sometimes have their tip bend slightly in one direction, in order for them to follow a certain centreline of the vessel better. Now I am wondering, why this helps for steering/ choosing the right path?
Any hints/ literature is appreciated, Thank you a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! Questions here are required to show results of prior research. As described in the [help] and the reasons mentioned in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411), this demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and helps you get more specific and relevant answers. Please [edit] your question with links to or references to what you've found in your search. Otherwise your question may be closed.

Comment: I think what you're asking about are what's known as steerable catheters. Those are catheters than can bend and flex the way the doctor wants using a control on the handle. If you lookup steerable catheters, I think you'll find more useful information.

Comment: @CareyGregory Guidewires aren't the same as steerable catheters, they're usually used with a traditional vascular catheter/introducer.

Answer (score 2):

An endovascular wire moves by being manipulated mechanically at the shaft, outside the body. All you can do with a wire is push/pull it and twist it. When you push forward, it goes the way the tip is pointed, roughly (it also depends on the geometry of the vessel and how it biases against the vessel wall; it's pretty intuitive if you try it in a model).

If you bend the tip, you can change which way it points by rotating the shaft. If the tip isn't bent, you can't steer. Even wires that are shipped unbent may be bent by the practitioner according to their favorite preference of bend length and angle (and this preference may depend on the case, too).

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC8612832/ is the first article that came up when I searched *endovascular wire guidance* though it discusses a broad variety of wire properties.